# Making a local instance of AccessMap (open-source project)

Tags: database, gis, pipeline, openstreetmap, open-source

I am trying to implement the [**AccessMap**](https://github.com/AccessMap/) project for my city but I have two problems:

1. The data collection (what kind of data do I need to collect and how)
2. How do I insert the data that I have collected inside the platform?

For the first problem, I have collected some data from OpenStreetMap with the use of the osmnx python library which I think might be correct although any guidelines on that would be appreciated.

Now for the second problem, The app seems to have some sort of an [API](https://github.com/AccessMap/accessmap) with a database to store the user data but I am not sure if the map data should also be stored there.

In the app's [documentation](https://github.com/AccessMap/accessmap) they mention a transportation.geojson which must contain the city network data in order for it to appear on the app (I already passed some dummy data to it and it kinda worked). My question here is:

Do I generate the data using their [repo](https://github.com/OpenSidewalks/opensidewalks-data) (or osmnx as their repo is very outdated) and then pass it in the transportation file by hand, or do I make a pipeline to connect the two (here the main question is **how**)?

I tried to build a local database for the API but the app does not seem to feed with data from the database (but from the transportation.geojson file instead).